# Vue - Use a prop in a v-for syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

How do I use a prop value in a `v-for` syntax? I have an array like below:

```
[
  {
    "id": 287,
    "author": 1,
    "featured_media": 288,
    "categories": [
      107
    ],
    "tags": [
      86
    ],
    "authors": [
      61
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 224,
    "author": 1,
    "featured_media": 225,
    "categories": [
      107
    ],
    "tags": [
      21
    ],
    "authors": [
      77
    ]
  }
]
```

Usually to use v-for I do `v-for="category in post.categories"` or `v-for="category in post.authors"`. However, i'd like to be able to set the "categories", "tags", or "authors" part of the syntax through a prop.

So if I use the component like this `<post-taxonomies :post="post" type="authors"/>` or `<post-taxonomies :post="post" type="tags"/>`, v-for can take the "type" property from the array.

Can I do that?

My component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="type">
      <archive-link
        v-for="author in post.type" <----make this dependent on the "type" prop value??
        :key="post.id+author"
        archive-type="authors"
        :archive-id="author"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const ArchiveLink = () => import(
  /* webpackChunkName: "posts" */
  '@/components/utility/ArchiveLink')

export default {
  name: 'PostTaxonomies',
  components: { ArchiveLink },
  props: {
    post: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {}
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use brackets in v-for for the dynamic property.

`v-for="author in post[type]"`

Comment: It will return an array carrying one object. You should use v-for="author in post[type][0]"

Comment: I think asker wants to loop trough that array, not displaying the first item.